# No current to GFCI outlet after installation in to junction box

Tags: gfci

I just installed a new 20 amp GFCI in an outdoor outlet. There are only three wires coming out of the junction box, the black, white and copper wire. After installation, I turned the current back on to ensure the outlet was functioning correctly. It was. I wrapped the GFCI in electrical tape to cover the terminals. I then inserted the outlet into the junction box and it stopped working. Additionally I tested to see if there is no voltage in the neutral wire or the metal junction box. There is none. The wires coming out of the junction box do not have any obvious defects. The GFCI does not trip, it just receives no current after installation into the junction box. The only other device on the same circuit breaker is getting current and operates fine.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you pull out the GFCI again does it work?

Comment: Use a **volt ohm meter** to get more information by testing the wires themselves.

Comment: Did you torque down the screws with a torque screwdriver (or at least Quite Hard)?  Also check the other device to see that the wire connections are OK there.

Comment: Wrapping the terminals with electrical tape is not a good idea, condensation can collect on it and cause a trip. I would remove that, then check to make sure one of the wires didn't come off when you did that.

Comment: @jraef Actually wrapping contacts is suggested for oversized devices like GFCI’s  and listed electrical tape is one approved method of sealing. I would be verifying that the main breaker did not trip when reinstalling the receptacle, the insulation could have some minor damage and be tripping the breaker if not that check your connections to the receptacle itself.